# SQL case assignment equal distribution based on group

Tags: sql

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that can equally distribute a list of patients to case managers based on different groupings.

My data has a table with a list of patients that are assigned a LOW or HIGH priority:

| PATIENTID | PRIORITY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LOW |
| 2 | LOW |
| 3 | HIGH |
| 4 | LOW |
| 5 | HIGH |

etc.

I also have a table of case managers that can be assigned to these patients based on the patient's priority. There are five managers per priority grouping:

| CASE MANAGER | PRIORITY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LOW |
| 2 | LOW |
| 3 | LOW |
| 4 | LOW |
| 5 | LOW |
| 6 | HIGH |
| 7 | HIGH |
| 8 | HIGH |
| 9 | HIGH |
| 10 | HIGH |

I'm trying to distribute a case manager to each patient based on the patient's priority and the case manager's assigned priority in such a way that each case manager has as close to an equal amount of patients as possible, within their priority group. I know I'd have to join the case manager table to the patient table so that I can run the assignments within group, but I'm not sure how to do this in a way that distributes the case managers equally.

Additionally, if I run this on a weekly basis, I want to be able to keep the existing case manager assignments to the first set of patients and only assign a case manager to new patients in the same equally-distributed manner. So for example, if I run this program today and the five patients above get a case manager assignment, I want to be able to run this again next week when five new patients come in and only assign them a manager (so the initial five patients would keep their original case manager). My initial thought was to keep a total of the # of assignments for each case manager as a column in that table, so that when this algorithm gets re-run I can just make new assignments based on who has the fewest assigned cases to date. But I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea. Perhaps this will help you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AssignPatientsToCaseManagers 
AS
BEGIN
  -- Join Patient and CaseManager tables based on priority
  DECLARE @availableManagers TABLE (
      CaseManagerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
      CurrentAssignedPatients INT DEFAULT (0)
  );

  INSERT INTO @availableManagers (CaseManagerID)
  SELECT DISTINCT CaseManagerID
  FROM CaseManager;

  UPDATE am
  SET am.CurrentAssignedPatients = p.AssignedPatients
  FROM @availableManagers am
  INNER JOIN Patient p ON am.CaseManagerID = p.CaseManagerID;

  MERGE Patient p
  USING (
      SELECT PatientID, Priority, CaseManagerID
      FROM Patient
      WHERE CaseManagerID IS NULL -- Identify new patients only for updates
      UNION ALL
      SELECT PatientID, Priority, NULL AS CaseManagerID -- Include existing patients for initial assignment
  ) AS newPatients
  ON (p.PatientID = newPatients.PatientID)
  WHEN MATCHED AND p.CaseManagerID IS NULL THEN -- Assign case manager to new patients only
    UPDATE SET
      p.CaseManagerID = am.CaseManagerID,
      am.CurrentAssignedPatients = am.CurrentAssignedPatients + 1
  FROM @availableManagers am
  WHERE am.Priority = newPatients.Priority 
  AND am.CurrentAssignedPatients < (SELECT AVG(CurrentAssignedPatients) FROM @availableManagers); -- Threshold for available manager

  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN -- Insert new patients (handled by UNION ALL)
    INSERT (PatientID, Priority)
    VALUES (newPatients.PatientID, newPatients.Priority);

  DROP TABLE @availableManagers;
END;
GO

EXEC AssignPatientsToCaseManagers;
```

###### Explanation:

A temporary table `@availableManagers` is created to store case manager IDs and track their currently assigned patients. The `MERGE` statement combines `INSERT` and `UPDATE` functionalities. It joins the `Patient` table with a virtual table containing both new and existing patients (using `UNION ALL`). For new patients `CaseManagerID IS NULL`, it assigns a case manager from the `@availableManagers` table based on priority and availability (using a subquery to check the average assigned patients). Existing patients are skipped to preserve their assignments.